# Can't access base properties in derived class (C#)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having trouble with inheritance/polymorphism in C#/Xamarin.Forms. There's multiple things I'd think I would be allowed to do, but I'm not, and from what I gather it seems I'm not inheriting correctly, so first things first:

### Declarations

```
public abstract partial class CommonCell : ContentView, ICellSection
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Title", typeof(string), typeof(CommonCell), default(string));
    public string Title
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
        }
    public CommonCell()
            : base()
        {

        }
    public virtual IInputType GetInputType()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

In the same file i also declare this derived class:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class CellSection<T>: CommonCell where T : View, IInputType
{
    private T _inputType;
    public T InputType
        {
            get { return _inputType; }
            set { _inputType = value; } //plus more stuff here
        }
    public CellSection ()
            :base()
        {
            //Layout Initialization
        }
    public override IInputType GetInputType() //I get an error here (Problem 2)
        {
            return InputType;
        }
}
```

I've only included one property and one method to demonstrate my problem, but there are many more declared the same way...

### Problem 1

What happens is that when I create a new CellSection, like this:

```
CellSection<TextInput> section1 = new CellSection<TextInput>();
section1.Title = "New Title"; //This line is not allowed
```

I'm not allowed to access the Title property...

Error message: `CellSection<TextInput>' does not contain a definition for 'Title'`

I've been able to access it by adding the following code to the `CellSection<T>` class:

```
public string Title
    {
        get { return base.Title; }
        set { base.Title = value; }
    }
```

but this seems so damn unnecessary and redundant... There must be another way...

### Problem 2

The other problem I have is that I'm not allowed to override the virtual method `GetInputType()`, it is in the code above as well, but this is the line I'm talking about:

```
public override IInputType GetInputType()
{
    return InputType;
}
```

Error message: `'CellSection<T>.GetInputType()': no suitable method found to override`

### Problem 3

The final problem is that when I'm, from a different class/file, attempt to reference/cast a `CellSection<T>` to `ICellSection` (which is implemented by the base class `CommonCell`)

```
List<ICellSection> Sections = new List<ICellSection> { section1, section2 };
```

I get an error that it's not allowed.

Error message: `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'CellSection<TextInput>' to 'ICellSection'`

This one I'm more unsure about as I don't know if it's even possible (can't find examples on it), but the problem 1 and 2 I just don't understand why won't work as they seem pretty straight forward...

Comment: If `CommonCell` is an abstract class anyways, why do you implement a virtual method that just throws a `NotImplementedException`? Why not declare the method itself abstract `public abstract IInputType GetInputType();`?

Comment: could you please error message screenshot which you get while building this project?

Comment: You can't set a readonly property's value - TitleProperty

Comment: @AnkushJain I've updated the original post with specific error messages (the comment wouldn't format properly).

Comment: @Adwaenyth I've tried both, and they give the same error.

Comment: @AnkushJain The readonly modifier is avoided with the GetValue() and SetValue() methods. These are built-in Xamarin methods, and all examples I've seen use the readonly modifier. By the way, the code works fine if I do everything in the same class, but not when I use inheritance. The problem though is that I need to avoid using a specific type in references to the generic class CellSection<T>, that's the reason I need to split it up into two classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every customer support employee ever:

> "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Me:

> "Dam'it... Yes, yes I have turned it off and on again"

Turns out this problem was a Visual Studio or Xamarin bug. I deleted all relevant files and added them again (copying and pasting the same old code into the new files). Boom! Everything is now inherited properly. I have no idea what caused the issue, as I assumed it would be a reference problem in the .projitems file, but there's basically no change to that file (checking in git a few lines switched place but that's it).

If anyone else has the same or a similar issue in the future: I had restarted Visual Studio several times while having this problem. I had restarted my machine at least once while having this problem.